# Jquery prop on checkbox doesn't work on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox in my page that is checked by default. I try to use LocalStorage and save the value there if a user changes it.

This is what I have done:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            $('#togglelist').prop('checked', localStorage.ListCheckbox);

            $("#togglelist").change(function () {
                localStorage.ListCheckbox = $('#togglelist').prop('checked');
            });

    </script>
```

I can see on the developer console the value changing while clicking on the checkbox. Also, if I leave it unchecked (false), on the next page load, the local storage has false as value, but the checkbox is still checked.

Edit: I cannot use the `checkboxradio('refresh')` since I don't have the JQM.

Comment: `$('#togglelist').prop('checked', localStorage.ListCheckbox==='true');`

Comment: Omg. This is it. Can you please add it as an answer?

Comment: As `non-empty` string is always truthy and `localStorage` always stores data in form of `string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As `non-empty` string is always truthy and `localStorage` always stores data in form of `string`

Test the value of `localStorage` with `string`

```
$('#togglelist').prop('checked', localStorage.ListCheckbox==='true');
```

Comment: Accept the answer in 9 minutes (due to limitations of SE)